# Loop in Oracle SQL, comparing one month to another

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to draft a SQL query which does the following:

Compare current week (e.g. week 10) amount to the average amount over previous 4 weeks (Week# 9,8,7,6).

Now I need to run the query on a monthly basis so say for weeks (10,11,12,13). 
As of now I am running it four times giving the week parameter on each run.

For example my current query is something like this :

```
select account_id, curr.amount,hist.AVG_Amt
from 
(
    select 
        to_char(run_date,'IW') Week_ID,
        sum(amount) Amount,
        account_id
    from Transaction t
    where to_char(run_date,'IW') = '10'
    group by account_id,to_char(run_date,'IW')
) curr,
(
    select account_id,
        sum(amount) / count(to_char(run_date,'IW')) as AVG_Amt
    from Transactions 
    where to_char(run_date,'IW') in ('6','7','8','9')
    group by account_id
) hist
where 
    hist.account_id = curr.account_id
    and curr.amount > 2*hist.AVG_Amt;
```

As you can see, if I have to run the above query for week 11,12,13 I have to run it three separate times. Is there a way to consolidate or structure the query such that I only run once and I get the comparison data all together?

Just an additional info, I need to export the data to Excel (which I do after running query on the PL/SQL developer) and export to Excel.

Thanks!

-Abhi

Comment: which version of oracle are you using?

Comment: I am using Oracle 11G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a correlated sub-query to get the sum of amounts for the last 4 weeks for a given week.

```
select 
    to_char(run_date,'IW') Week_ID,
    sum(amount) curAmount,
    (select sum(amount)/4.0 from transaction 
     where account_id = t.account_id
     and to_char(run_date,'IW') between to_char(t.run_date,'IW')-4 
                                        and to_char(t.run_date,'IW')-1
    ) hist_amount,
    account_id
from Transaction t
where to_char(run_date,'IW') in ('10','11','12','13')
group by account_id,to_char(run_date,'IW')
```

Edit: Based on OP's comment on the performance of the query above, this can also be accomplished using `lag` to get the previous row's value. Count of number of records present in the last 4 weeks can be achieved using a `case` expression.

```
with sum_amounts as 
(select to_char(run_date,'IW') wk, sum(amount) amount, account_id 
 from Transaction
 group by account_id, to_char(run_date,'IW')
)
select wk, account_id, amount, 
1.0 * (lag(amount,1,0) over (order by wk) + lag(amount,2,0) over (order by wk) +
       lag(amount,3,0) over (order by wk) + lag(amount,4,0) over (order by wk)) 
/ case when lag(amount,1,0) over (order by wk) <> 0 then 1 else 0 end +
  case when lag(amount,2,0) over (order by wk) <> 0 then 1 else 0 end +
  case when lag(amount,3,0) over (order by wk) <> 0 then 1 else 0 end +
  case when lag(amount,4,0) over (order by wk) <> 0 then 1 else 0 end 
as hist_avg_amount 
from sum_amounts
```

Comment: Good idea! However there is a challenge. I am doing the average based on the number of week data available so "select sum(amount)/4.0 " won't work if there are only 3 (or 2) weeks with data.

Comment: This worked really great! Instead of 4 I used the following: select sum(amount)/count(distinct to_char(run_date,'IW'))

Comment: Update 7Nov: Performance wise this query is a disaster. On my dataset it too almost 20hrs to complete :(

Comment: @Abhishek .. i added one more version using `lag`. check the performance of this query.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is what you are looking for:

```
with lagt as (select to_char(run_date,'IW') Week_ID, sum(amount) Amount, account_id 
  from Transaction t 
  group by account_id, to_char(run_date,'IW'))
select Week_ID, account_id, amount, 
  (lag(amount,1,0) over (order by week) + lag(amount,2,0) over (order by week) +
   lag(amount,3,0) over (order by week) + lag(amount,4,0) over (order by week)) / 4 as average 
  from lagt;
```